# Partition a FetchedRC (custom order of cells)

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a Note and Tag Relationship which I am trying to sort a `tableView` by. I am wanting to use a FetchedRC like my other tableViews but am unsure how I would continue using it and have the correct sorting. I am trying to sort by if the `Note` contains the `Tag` as a relationship. How can I use a FetchedRC and get this result? This is my current working code that bypasses the FetchedRC and makes its own customOrder Tag array, I just need it somehow to be sorting on the FetchedRC because I would like the built in updating:

```
private func fetch() {
    let request = Tag.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Tag>
    let primarySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Tag.notes, ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [primarySortDescriptor]
    do {
        var fetch = try context.fetch(request)
        fetch.partition(by: { !($0.notes?.contains(self.note!))! })
        self.customOrder = fetch
    }
}
```